# Linux skip /root/.gvfs when executing df command with non-root user

Tags: linux

Is there any way where we can skip /root/.gvfs check when executing df command with non-root user ?

I know we can solve this issue by either giving permissions or umount that file(till machine is rebooted) by logging into the machine with root user.

But the problem is I should not log in into that machine with root user. I have to do everything with non-root user only and non-root user does not have privilege to chanfe permissions of /root/.gvfs file and to execute umount command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution for my own question :)

In df command you can pass the file system types which you would like to exclude, in this case it is 'fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon'.

So when I execute the below the command I no more get this message "df: `/root/.gvfs': Permission denied"

**df -x fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon**

For more details one can look into df --help option.